# VB - SETFOCUS - Focus a textbox after failed validation

Tags: visual-basic-6

Olá
Estou a tentar usar a função de SetFocus mas quando faço debug dá erro.
Portanto, consoante a validação de if e else em certos casos surge uma msgbox que alerta para o erro e o utilizador ao a fechar eu queria que automaticamente fosse seleccionada a caixa onde está o erro.

```
ElseIf txtFind.Text = "" Then
            validacao = validacao + False
            MsgBox("Please fill the XX!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ERRO")
 txtFind.Text.SetFocus
```

Em suma, se o campo está vazio o utilizador recebe um erro e quero encaminhar logo para o campo em falta.
Obrigado

Comment: Exatamente o que o davidterra respondeu, você não pode setar o foco para a propriedade do Textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta apenas txtFind.SetFocus

```
If txtFind.Text = "" Then
    validacao = validacao + False
    Call MsgBox("Please fill the XX!", vbCritical, "ERRO")
    txtFind.SetFocus
End If
```